# Is sankalpam/sankalp important in order to do homam/havan? Can havan/homam be performed without sankalpam/sankalp?

Tags: scripture, vedas, belief, homam

I just want to know if a havan/homam can be performed without sankalp/sankalpam

Comment: Sankalpa usually precedes every Hindu Karma or rituals. Even before bathing Sankalpa mantras are chanted.

Comment: Without sankalp if you do a homam it is worthless. The year, month, Ayana, Ruthu,Thithi, Paksha, star,Yoga, Karana plays a significant role in sankalp.

Comment: think of sankalpa like signing a contract before starting a job. sure, you can do a job without signing, but then it cannot be easily enforced legally. Krishna says in Gita that manushya and devas fulfill each other's desires (through yagna for devas, and in result, devas provide rain, water, wind etc.). this sankalpa is a contract declaration.

Answer (score 5):

I have found some references in [this Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKYBeJrKF_E) (Sankalpa Vidhi), which talks about why one should always perform Sankalpa before embarking upon any Hindu ritual. It also explains a Vidhi (method) of performing Sankalpa.

In this video, we find slokas (which are supposedly) from Manu Smriti, Markandeya Purana which explain that full results of the rituals are not obtained if Sankalpa is not uttered.

> Sankalpena vina karma yatkinchit kurute narah |
>  Phalam
> chapyalpakama tasya dharmasyarcha kshayo bhavet || (Manu)
>
> Sankalpa muloh kamah vai yajnah sankalpa sambabhah |
>  Vritani yajna
> dharmashcha sarve sankalpajnah smritah || (Markandeya Purana)

Translation as per the narrator/author is roughly "If any Karma is performed without uttering Sankalpa, then the full fruits are not obtained, some fruits are lost and half of them are obtained".

Another verse is also quoted, which specifically talks about performing Yajna/Homa:

> Masa paksha tithinashcha nimittanam cha sarvashah |
>  Ullekhanam na
> kurvano na tasya phala bhagabhavet ||
>
> If before performing the Yajna, month, Tithi, Nakshtra etc. and the purpose are not
> mentioned in the Sankalpa, then the fruits of the Yajna are not obtained.

So, it is always wise to utter Sankalpa before doing the Yajna.